# container not reachable in docker compose simplest example

Tags: typescript, http, networking, docker-compose, fastapi

the [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) says:

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

but I created a very simple app that I can't get to work. My scripts are:
(also [here](https://gist.github.com/franchesoni/04c64bbd1b2af16dd245e58d9a5a4291))

`frontend/index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Hit me</button>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`frontend/src/main.ts`

```js
async function btn(): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Button clicked")
    const content = await (await fetch("http://backend/")).json()
    console.log(content)
}

document.getElementById("btn")!.addEventListener("click", btn);
```

(default `tsc --init`)

`backend/app/main.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

`backend/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code/app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

`backend/requirements.txt`

```
fastapi
uvicorn
```

and finally
`compose.yaml`

```
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend/.
    ports:
      - "80"
  frontend:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
```

I would expect to reach `http://backend/` when I hit the button as the documentation suggests, but I get `GET http://backend/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. How am I supposed to access backend from frontend and viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

You are tight about docker networks, but your frontend code doesn't run in a docker container, it runs in the browser. In your example, you're exposing the API on port 80, so from the tyoescript code, you should be able to connect to `http://localhost`.